# Using strtotime to find date before a date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a very simple question I would like to pose, but the answer is eluding me. I have a date (such as "first sunday in April") and I am trying to find the day before this, using the php strtotime function. It occurred to me that this would be harder using any other bespoke method as I'd have to take into account the number of days in a month in case (for instance), the first sunday in April was the 1st. Ive tried the obvious solutions like "first sunday in April - 1 day" and "1 day before first Sunday in April".

I'm hoping it can be done in one step rather than find the output of strtotime and then perform arithmetic on its results.

I'm sure it must be simple. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the different relative date/time formats at:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Thanks, I really must flush out my brain with ethanol. It seems I had forgotten the word "yesterday" :(